# Allowing extra parameters on a Powershell advanced function

Tags: powershell

*Environmental note: I'm currently targetting PowerShell 5.1 because 6 has unrelated limitations I can't work around yet.*

In the Powershell module I'm writing, there is one main function that's sort of a conglomeration of a bunch of the smaller functions. The main function has a superset of the smaller function's parameters. The idea is that calling the main function will call each smaller function with the necessary parameters specified on the main.  So for example:

```
function Main { [CmdletBinding()] param($A,$B,$C,$D)
    Sub1 -A $A -B $B
    Sub2 -C $C -D $D
}

function Sub1 { [CmdletBinding()] param($A,$B)
    "$A $B"
}

function Sub2 { [CmdletBinding()] param($C,$D)
    "$C $D"
}
```

Explicitly specifying the sub-function parameters is both tedious and error prone particularly with things like `[switch]` parameters. So I wanted to use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) to make things easier. Instead of specifying each parameter on the sub-function, I'll just splat `$PSBoundParameters` from the parent onto each sub-function like this:

```
function Main { [CmdletBinding()] param($A,$B,$C,$D)
    Sub1 @PSBoundParameters
    Sub2 @PSBoundParameters
}
```

The immediate problem with doing this is that the sub-functions then start throwing an error for any parameter they don't have defined such as, "`Sub1 : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'C'.`" If I remove the `[CmdletBinding()]` declaration, things work but I lose all the benefits of those subs being [advanced functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-5.1).

So my current workaround is to add and additional parameter on each sub-function that uses the [`ValueFromRemainingArguments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1#valuefromremainingarguments-argument) parameter attribute like this:

```
function Sub1 { [CmdletBinding()] 
    param($A,$B,[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]$Extra)
    "$A $B"
}

function Sub2 { [CmdletBinding()]
    param($C,$D,[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]$Extra)
    "$C $D"
}
```

Technically, this works well enough. The sub-functions get their specific params and the extras just get ignored. If I was writing this just for me, I'd move on with my life and be done with it.

But for a module intended for public consumption, there's an annoyance factor with that `-Extra` parameter being there. Primarily, it shows up in `Get-Help` output which means I have to document it even if just to say, "Ignore this."

Is there an extra step I can take to make that extra parameter effectively invisible to end users? Or am I going about this all wrong and there's a better way to allow for extra parameters on an advanced function?

Comment: *I have to document it even if just to say, "Ignore this."* You better to document this and it should be not *"Ignore this."*, but something like this: "Due to this hack any misspelled parameter will be silently ignored instead of providing relevant error message."

Comment: My usual approach is to export only "wrapper" functions that call internal (i.e., not user-facing) functions in the module.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart That's...not actually a bad idea. So the public sub would omit the $Extra param and just pass everything directly to the private sub. And the main could still call the private sub with the big splat. It adds a touch more kludge, but gets rid of my primary gripe.

Comment: I don't find it to be a kludge at all but rather a sensible modular approach. (To each his own, I guess.)

Comment: Apologies, kludge was a poor word choice. I just meant it's technically more code to maintain.

Comment: IMO modules lend themselves very naturally to this kind of design, so that may just be a matter of perception.

Comment: Bill, did you want to throw this advice into an answer and I'll mark it accepted? Or should I just do it?

Comment: @RyanBolger - done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My usual approach is to export only "wrapper" functions that call internal (i.e., not user-facing) functions in the module.